# Writing a function to console.log, how can i pass multiple values?

Tags: javascript

It's hard to write `console.log` every time so I created a function for it,

```js
function showi(input){
 console.log(input);
 }
 
showi('hello');
```

But the problem is that, It can't pass multiple arguments. **For example:**

```js
function showi(input){
 console.log(input);
 }
 
let array1 = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

for(const [index, value] of array1.entries()){
 showi(index, value);
 }
 
//value will also print if I use console.log instead of `showi` function
```

**How can I pass multiple values in `showi` function?**

Comment: If you can use ES6, replace `input` by `...input` both in the function header and in the `console.log` call.

Comment: Use `function showi() { console.log(...arguments); }`

Comment: @Chris G console.log(...arguments); works, Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you find `console.log` is big to use then just assign it to a variable like `logIt` like below. In this case you can use this like how you are using `console.log` with single or any number of parameters

```js
window.logIt=console.log;
logIt('hello');
let array1 = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
logIt('array1 : ',array1);
```

Comment: Which one would be better `window.logIt` or making a function `logIt()`, What's the difference between them?

Comment: @Ankit you can either use `window.logIt=console.log` or `logIt=console.log` to call `logIt` with any number of parameters like `console.log`

Comment: How come `let print = document.write;` don't work the same way?

Answer (score 1):

### Solution 1 - Use arguments

```
function showi(){
 console.log(...arguments);
}
```

### Solution 2 - Use your own argument's name

```
function showi(...textToPrint){
 console.log(...textToPrint);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `arguments` object

```
function showi() {
    console.log(...arguments);
}
```

Or you can also use rest and spread operators in es6 -

```
function showi(...args) {
    console.log(...args);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if input is an array using `Array.isArray` and based on that show the content.

```js
function showMe(input) {
  if (Array.isArray(input)) {
    console.log(...input);
  } else {
    console.log(input);
  }
}

showMe('sandip');
showMe(['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

Similarly you can add other checks.

Comment: `typeof input === 'array'` there's no `array` type in javascript

Comment: My bad, modified the answer.

Comment: also, OP wants to pass multiple params, not an array.